# Can Thinking Sphinx be used with SQlite3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I know Sphinx requires you to have MySQL but is it possible to have the MySQL server running and still use the SQLite3 Database for Thinking Sphinx and the rest of my application until I go into production? I'm confused on if you only can use MySQL or both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sphinx does not work with SQLite. So unless you want some models (that aren't searchable using Sphinx) on SQLite and the rest in MySQL or PostgreSQL - and that is more of a headache than it's worth - then you should just use either MySQL or PostgreSQL for your Rails application, and not use SQLite at all.